# Error comparando cantidades en php

Tags: php, comparaciones

Tengo este código

```
 $gastoPaciente = (double) Session::get('gastoPaciente');
 $gastoPersonal = (double) Session::get('gastoPersonal');
 $presupuestoPaciente = (double) Session::get('presupuestoPaciente');
 $presupuestoPersonal = (double) Session::get('presupuestoPersonal');
 $per = $personal * $price;
 $gastoPersonal = $gastoPersonal + $per;
 var_dump($gastoPersonal);
 var_dump($presupuestoPersonal);
 var_dump($gastoPersonal > $presupuestoPersonal);
```

y me regresa esto

```
float(5307) float(5307) bool(true)
```

Comment: ¿Si tu asignas los valores a  las variables también te pasa?

Comment: si hago esto var_dump(1 > 1); me regresa bool(false)

Comment: @Francisco, te aconsejo que utilices las funciones de [`BC Math`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.bc.php), por ejemplo, [`bccomp`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.bccomp.php)

Comment: @Marcos gracias voy a probar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En `PHP` existen casos donde la precisión decimal nos puede jugar en contra.

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php

$gastoPersonal = (double) '5306.00';
$presupuestoPersonal = (double) '5307.00';
$per = 1 * 1.00000000001; // Provocamos el error de precisión decimal
$gastoPersonal = $gastoPersonal + $per;

var_dump($gastoPersonal);
var_dump($presupuestoPersonal);
var_dump($gastoPersonal > $presupuestoPersonal);

//Result
float(5307)
float(5307)
bool(true)
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/44f2a2ba72de1e829fe8b0319b9a81ac09328f7a)</kbd>

Para estos casos específicos podemos utilizar la funciones de [`BC Math`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.bc.php)

> Para operaciones matemáticas de precisión arbitraria PHP ofrece la Calculadora Binaria, la cual admite números de cualquier tamaño y precisión, representados como strings.

Para este caso, por ejemplo, podemos utilizar [`bccomp`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.bccomp.php)

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php

$gastoPersonal = (double) '5306.00';
$presupuestoPersonal = (double) '5307.00';
$per = 1 * 1.00000000001;
$gastoPersonal = $gastoPersonal + $per;

var_dump($gastoPersonal);
var_dump($presupuestoPersonal);
var_dump(bccomp($gastoPersonal, $presupuestoPersonal, 2) > 0);

//Result
float(5307)
float(5307)
bool(false)
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/50d18e429b4f024e340a5d90b51d7fb62fd5ceaf)</kbd>

Comment: muchisimas gracias, funcionó perfectamente!!